# Recommended Icon for Dashboard

Tags: icons, dashboard

Can you recommend me about the icon for the dashboard, I have been looking at http://findicons.com/search/dashboard but get the icons like in the picture below.

[image]

I feel it's more like **clock** instead of the dashboard.

Comment: What's the content of your dashboard? Do you intend to use the dashboard icon without text?

Comment: They really do suck. Phew!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of starting with a cockpit or car dashboard metaphor, my choice would be to begin with something that is actually in the dashboard (or at least I assume is in your dashboard): namely, a graph or chart.

For example:
http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/icons/search/fugue/#keyword=chart

Comment: +1 for 'use something from your dashboard'.  One common icon trick is to use part of an object to stand in for the whole thing.

Answer (score 4):

Another take is, if you have a series of measures that are either "good" or "bad," then use a series of [traffic lights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_light_rating_system).  Starting there, an operator can see what the red items are, and drill further if needed.

For example:

[image]

So perhaps the icon would be:

[image]

Comment: Nice, but how then do you handle the red-green color-blindness problem?

Comment: Wilson: See updated first pic: the same way real traffic lights deal with color blindness :-)

Answer (score 3):

A dashboard could represent both momentarily values or statistical data over time. When you look at a dashboard representing web traffic (like Google Analytics) you are often interested in statistical data of last month, last week or last day. Thus Google Analaytics dashboard icon is a graph.

However, if you were to present instant values (such as your current car speed) the meter is preferred. *You need to decide which kind of dashboard you have*, in order to have the right representation.

One icon that does not look like a clock, but more like a meter would be this one:
[image: A possible dashboard icon]

Answer (score 2):

Stealing an extract from Benny's answer and your original image - rather than showing the complete dial, you can just focus in on a key part.  Here we're using a 64x64 pixel extract.  The second extract is from the Tango dashboard.

......  [image] ........ [image] ......

And here's the full Tango dashboard icon from which the second extract is taken:

.............[image]

My view is that it doesn't shrink below 64 pixels in height well, but the extract is usable at 48x48.

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dashboard.svg

Answer (score 0):

Is this a data based dashboard? If is not, the cockpit metric icons are misleading would probably be better a checklist icons (some dots with some lines)...
if is a data dashboard then try to make an icon that is related to the content of the dashboard